# hardware and software requirements to launch an ERC20 Token

Tags: hardware, require

Pardon me I'm new in this.

I'm trying to launch my ERC20 token. So What are the hardware and software requirements for an ideal transfers handling server system?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question, but ERC20 tokens do not have a "transfers handling server system" because they exist on the blockchain and not on a centralized proprietary server. All transfers occur by creating transactions on the blockchain.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook Yes right, but what possible precautions do I need to consider to keep everything fail-safe??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is all done on the public Ethereum blockchain, then you don't need to worry about a server. People can transfer your ERC20 tokens without you running anything at all (after you deploy the contract, at least).

Comment: Yes that's right.. But If I'm launching an ICO, what could be the possible requirements or the precautions that I need to consider to make everything fail-safe?? Thanks!

Comment: Also, is MyEtherWallet a good option to keep as the address to accept incoming ether in exchange of the token or is there any better option??

Comment: @prashantNagawade I think your question is invalid because you're starting from an assumption that is wrong. You should not be using a server (or MyEtherWallet) for your ICO. Your ICO sale is just a separate contract from your ERC20 token contract, which holds a balance of your token, and issues them automatically when it receives ETH to the `payable` function. I suggest doing some more reading on how ICOs typically work on Ethereum in a decentralized way.

Comment: The requirements and precautions are just to have the token/crowdsale contracts be well audited. Also, you don't use MyEtherWallet to send/receive eth from the ICO. The smart contract does it on chain. You'll have to use another wallet to collect the proceeds from the ICO, which could be MyEtherWallet (but should be a hardware wallet to be safe).

Comment: @flygoing Thanks! Could u please tell where can I do the auditing of my contracts, I mean the legitimate ones..??

Comment: There are multiple smart contract auditing companies available on Google. I can offer my auditing services as well. Note: Smart contract audits aren't cheap.

Comment: @flygoing well thanks for it, I'll definitely think about that.. Could u please give me any sort of contact of urs so that I can contact u on behalf of my company to go further?? And I'll remove this irrelevent comment as soon as I get the contact. Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: @PrashantNagawade Glad to help. I just added you on LinkedIn if you want to discuss further.